# Jekyll Static Page CSS Not Rendering

Tags: sass, jekyll

I am building a blog for myself using Jekyll, however, when I open the page in my browser, the SCSS fails to load. I try to navigate to the SCSS file through my browser but to no avail, the browser believes that the SCSS does not exist.

Here is how I add the stylesheet to the HTML:

`<link rel="stylesheet"  type="style/css"  href="/_sass/_base.scss">`

I did this to all of my stylesheets, and yet the it doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not link to stylesheets with an href to `"/_sass/_base.scss"`.

Instead you should do the following:

- create another directory to hold your "stylesheet", say, `css/`.
- then add an empty stylesheet with an empty front matter block (**required**)

  ```
  ---
  ---

  // this is an empty stylesheet named "style.scss"
  // use @import here to load partials from your _sass folder
  ```
- import your partial(s) into the above "stylesheet".

  ```
  ---
  ---

  // this is an empty stylesheet named "style.scss"
  // use @import here to load partials from your _sass folder

  @import "base";
  @import "mixins";
  ```
- link your HTML page with the stylesheet:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href="{{ 'css/style.css' | relative_url }}">
  ```

...and done!

---

Takeaways:

- Import files from your `_sass` into a "dedicated stylesheet".
- The dedicated stylesheet must contain the front matter block (can be empty).
- Link your HTML file with the dedicated stylesheet.
- Linked file has a `.css` extension even if your source file was `css/style.scss` or `css/style.sass`
- You may hard-code the markup or use a Liquid construct to link the stylesheet.
- When using a Liquid construct, prefer using the `relative_url` filter instead of using 
   `{{ 'css/style.css' | prepend: site.baseurl }}` or `{{ site.baseurl }}/css/style.css`

Comment: Jekyll has already autogenerated a css folder and a file with the font matter block. I tried using it. Still nothing.

Comment: *How did you try using it..?* Remember, the more information you give, the easier it is to resolve the issue..

Comment: Jekyll auto generated the css folder. In it was a file with the format that you posted in your answer. I linked it to (at first) index.html and the problem persisted. I tried linking it to all of the html files I'm using, but still no progress.

Comment: I may be able to help if you can host your repository on GitHub and post the public link for that repository

Comment: sent you a PR.. Merge it and you should see the CSS picked up properly..